# epstopdf error in LyX due to wrong $$o and $$i variables

Tags: lyx, epstopdf, underscore

I am having trouble with LyX not converting my files from PostScript to PDF. I am using Ubuntu 20.04, but the issue was there in Ubuntu 19.10, I just did not need the functionality then. Let's assume that my file path is "~/home/path/to/file/my graph.eps". When I try to compile the file, I am shown the following message:

```
An error occurred while running:
epstopdf
--outfile="0_home_path_to_file_my_graph.pdf"
"0_home_path_to_file_my_graph.eps"
```

And then

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: 
File `0_home_path_to_file_my_graph.pdf' 
not found: using draft setting.
```

I believe the problem is that all the `'\'` and `' '` characters are converted to underscores `'_'`, unless the error message is printed in a different manner, for whatever reason.

What's the solution here? I really don't want to convert all images by hand every time I make an edit to them.

Thanks,

Dmitrii.

Comment: Did you try it if the eps file has a simple name and is in the same directory as the .lyx file? Does that work?

Comment: It is hard to tell what is happening without any example, but why do you need to give the full path? why not just `\includegraphics{graph}` ?

Comment: No, putting the .eps file into the same folder did not help. The same issue persists, all the delimeters are underscores, the file path still begins with "0_home_..". From what is can gather, the full file path is added by LyX and I have no control over this. I have been using figure floats as per demand from by lab member, so I would like to fix the issue without changing the format. Problem is, he did not have the same problem :)

Comment: perhaps try rebuilding/reinstalling epstopdf to check it works on a simple known example.

Comment: Thanks, but if I run it from terminal, epstopdf works correctly. The problem seems to be in the path variable.

Comment: is your eps in the same folder as your lyx file or somewhere else?

Comment: I tried it both ways: in the folder and not. So far the only solution has been to convert every .eps file with `find . -name "*.eps" -exec epstopdf {} \;` and add every one of them as a pdf.

Comment: I see this same issue on Linux Mint 19.1.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you're saying that you can't see the image in the resulting PDF, or in Lyx on the display. I had this same error. I suspected it might be because Lyx (and TexLive) were installed in /usr/share, and my user didn't have write privileges there. To test this, I ran `sudo lyx` and got the following output:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
convert-im6.q16: not authorized `/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.BlzYGbBd8709/gconverthz8709.eps' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.BlzYGbBd8709/gconverthz8709.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
env: ‘epstopdf’: No such file or directory
support/Systemcall.cpp (291): Systemcall: 'epstopdf --outfile="32_usr_share_lyx_doc_clipart_mobius.pdf" "32_usr_share_lyx_doc_clipart_mobius.eps"' finished with exit code 127
Error: Cannot convert file
----------------------------------------
An error occurred while running:
epstopdf --outfile="32_usr_share_lyx_doc_clipart_mobius.pdf"
"32_usr_share_lyx_doc_clipart_mobius.eps"
```

The `env: 'epstopdf': No such file or directory` clued me in that I was actually missing that program/script. I had done `sudo tlmgr install epstopdf-pkg`, but that apparently did not install the script in my path anywhere (namely, `/usr/bin`).

Once I downloaded the [source](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/epstopdf) and manually installed it, the document would compile and I could see the images in the pdf. I still get the screen display error in Lyx, but I do not get the pop-up dialog with errors about epstopdf. Something's still not right, but maybe this helps a bit.